# Python - checking if user changed file

Tags: python

i've just written some code:

```
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    inputFile = open(inputPath, 'r')

    hasher.update(inputFile.read().encode('utf-8'))
    oldHash = hasher.hexdigest()
    newHash = ''

    while True:

        hasher.update(inputFile.read().encode('utf-8'))
        newHash = hasher.hexdigest()

        if newHash != oldHash:
            print('xd')

        oldHash = newHash
```

I need to quickly write sass compiler and that how I'm checking if user made any changes in file.It works but only when I add something to file, when I delete any word or char it doesn't detect it.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please take some time to create a [mcve]

Comment: You can't `read()` the same file twice. You have to re-open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of immediately checking the hash, you could just check the last modified time using [`os.path.getmtime(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

Considering:

```
in_path = "" # The sass/scss input file
out_path = "" # The css output file
```

Then checking if the file was changed simply do:

```
if not os.path.exists(out_path) or os.path.getmtime(in_path) > os.path.getmtime(out_path):
    print("Modified")
else:
    print("Not Modified")
```

After you've checked if the file was modified, you can then check the hash:

```
import hashlib

def hash_file(filename, block_size=2**20):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(block_size)
            if not data:
                break
            md5.update(data)
    return md5.digest()

if not os.path.exists(out_path) or hash_file(in_path) != hash_file(out_path):
    print("Modified")
else:
    print("Not Modified")
```

In total you can combine the if statement like this:

```
if not os.path.exists(out_path) \
        or os.path.getmtime(in_path) > os.path.getmtime(out_path) \
        or hash_file(in_path) != hash_file(out_path):
    print("Modified")
else:
    print("Not Modified")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's was really helpful :)

Comment: @KacperCzyż You're welcome! If it helped solve your question, then feel free to accept the answer :)